# как изменить цену деления оси графика

Tags: r, ggplot2

У меня есть две таблицы.

**vah_p_1**

```
x       y
0       4
0.25    5
0.27    6
0.29    7
0.31    8
0.33    10
0.34    13
0.36    16
0.37    20
0.38    23
0.39    28
0.4     37
0.41    43
0.42    55
0.43    67
0.44    81
0.45    94
0.46    118
0.47    143
0.48    187
0.49    225
```

**vah_o_1**

```
  x      y  
-17.2   -9
-14.2   -8
-9.27   -7
-6.9    -6
-4.09   -5
 0      -4
```

мне нужно построить на одном графике данные для обеих таблиц(Код внизу)

```
library(broom)
vah_p <- read.table(file = 'vah_p_1', header = TRUE)
y <- log2(vah_p$y)
x <- vah_p$x
mat_p <- data.frame(x, y)
error_p <- lm(y  ~ x, mat_p)
error_p <- broom::tidy(error_p)

vah_o <- read.table(file = 'vah_o_1', header = TRUE)
y <- log2((vah_o$y) * (-1))
x <- vah_o$x
mat_o <- data.frame(x, y)
error_o <- lm(y  ~ x, mat_o)
error_o <- broom::tidy(error_o)

library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(vah_p, aes(x = x,  y = y)) +
 geom_point() + geom_point(data = vah_o, aes(x = x,  y = y))
p
```

После компиляции я получил:
[image]

К сожалению данный график мне не подходит. Я хочу, чтобы для х в области (-20: 0) цена деления была 1, а в области (0: 1) была 0.01. К сожалению у меня не получилось это сделать.

Answer (score 1):

Вам необходима функция `scale_x_continuous`, `breaks` и `limits`, почитать о них можно например на официальной страничке `ggplot2` [здесь](http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/scale_continuous.html).

И для получения желаемой шкалы вставьте вот такую строчку:

```
p + scale_x_continuous(limits = c(-20, 1),
                       breaks = c(seq(-20, 0, 1), 
                                  seq(0, 1, 0.01)))
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
`limits` - задает пределы шкалы.

`breaks` - деления шкалы.

Первый `seq` создает последовательность от -20 до 0, второй от 0 до 1.

Только шкала от 0 до 1 получится очень насыщенной. Вам наверно с логарифмической шкалой нужно поиграть.

Comment: Мне кажется, это не волне точный ответ на вопрос. Такое впечатление, что @Zero149 хотел изменить ширину шага по оси Х. Это не похоже на правильное решение в любом случае. На мой взгляд, тут имеет смысл использовать `facet`